# Firebase realtime request inside map

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I have this javascript code

```
monthly = 0
await Promise.all(
    second.map(uid => {
        firebase.database().ref('user').child(uid).once('value', u => {
            u = u.val()
            if (u.pack.name != 'no pack'){
                monthly = monthly + 10
            }else{
                monthly = monthly +3
            }
        })
    })
).then(() => {
    console.log(monthly)
}
```

I need to use the variable monthly in the callback but i always get "0" as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything inside the map, so you're creating an array of `undefined`s, not an array of promises. So when you do Promise.all and `await` it, there's nothing to await.

```
monthly = 0
await Promise.all(
    second.map(uid => {
        // added a return
        return firebase.database().ref('user').child(uid).once('value', u => {
            u = u.val()
            if (u.pack.name != 'no pack'){
                monthly = monthly + 10
            }else{
                monthly = monthly +3
            }
        })
    })
)
console.log(monthly);
```